# What is the grammatical "logic" of ablative case in «Tuā et meā māximē interest tē ualēre» (Cic. Fam. 16.4)?

Tags: verbs, syntax, case

Assuming that ablative case is always a semantic case (see the typical lists of its associated meanings in Latin grammars), I was wondering if Latin speakers could still assign a synchronic more or less "compositional" interpretation to the ablative phrase of the verb *interest*, which indicates the person to whom the thing is important (e.g., *tua PARTE*?). As is well-known, this appears in ablative singular feminine of the possessives *mea, tua, sua, nostra, vestra*. Otherwise, it is expressed in genitive case (e.g., *omnium* and *nullius* below). The thing concerned can also be expressed by *ad* plus accusative, as shown in the fourth example.

> ***Tua** et **mea** maxime interest te  valere* (Cic. *Fam*. 16.4)
>
> *Interest **omnium** recte facere* (Cic. *Fin*. 2.72)
>
> *Magis **nullius** interest quam **tua**, Tite Otacili, non imponi cervicibus tuis onus* (Liv. 24, 8, 17)
>
> *Magni **ad honorem nostrum** interest me venire* (Cic. *Fam*. 16,1, 1)

Something similar happens with the verb *refert*. Cf. the diachronic explanation that relates *tua* to the prefix of this verb: *tua res fert > tuā refert*. E.g., vid. Woodcock (1959: 171): "By the apocope of final *s* in early Latin, this came to be pronounced *rēfert*. The first syllable was then thought to represent an ablative, and the last syllable of <*tua*> was lenghtened to agree with it": *A New Latin Syntax*, London: Methuen. However, I don't know how plausible this explanation (along with its alleged analogical extension to *interest*) is. So I was wondering if there is an alternative explanation for the ablative case in these examples.

> *Quid id refert **tua***?  (Pl. *Cas.* 330)
>
> *Faciundum aliquid quod **illorum** magis quam **sua** retulisse videretur* (Sal. *Jug*. 111, 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **purely synchronical** description of the whole picture in the first Century BC would be as follows.

Pronouns of the first and second person, as well as reflexives, don't have a single form in the genitive. In most contexts, possessive adjectives are used instead. Otherwise,

- For partitives and adpositions with *omnium,* ***nostrum, vestrum*** are used.
- For objects of such verbs as *memini, misereor* etc., and as objective genitives after nouns, ***mei, tui, sui, nostri, vestri.***
- With *interest* and *refert,* ***mea, tua, sua, nostra, vestra.***

If it quacks like a genitive, it is a genitive.

No grammar I know presents the facts in this way. Grammars usually cover a longer timespan in which still other forms are attested, and, basically, they are interested in the diachronical development.

Woodcock's theory *tua res fert > tua refert* does not convince me either. Maybe someone could find an allegedly implied astute construction, involving a feminine substantive in the ablative to agree with *mea, tua, sua,* somehow connected with another substantive in the genitive to go with *interest,* but it would be purely speculative, unattested, and actually unprovable.

Comment: There is an additional complex point with _refert_. Unlike _interest_, it seems to be the case that _refert_ does not usually coappear with a genitive in Early & Classical Latin (Sallust's example above is a sort of an exception) but it is true that there are a few examples of this use in Livy and mostly in Silver Latin.

Comment: So, if I've understood you correctly (and putting my comment above aside), what you're suggesting is that, for example, in Cicero's example in the title what we have is a {subjacent/abstract genitive} that turns out to be morphologically realized in the surface as ablative.

Comment: @Mitomino: I am actually saying something more. As they are surface realizations of a subjacent genitive, __synchronically__ those forms must be regarded as gender-insensitive genitives, even if we know that __diachronically__ they appear to have started out as feminine ablatives.